# How to stop dragged window becoming transparent and staying over others

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

I am having an issue on Windows 10 that I can't seem to be able to fix. This issue was asked about in a [Microsoft Forums Question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-become-and-stay-transparent/65a855a1-6517-4bf0-b60e-9e020a9e914e?rtAction=1642879734109), however the answer given was just to repair or reinstall Windows and remove all 3rd party applications. I would prefer to not have to reinstall my OS if possible, and instead find what exactly causes this issue to fix it directly.

The issue is as follows:

When dragging windowed applications they become translucent and the cursor changes to a red deskpin icon. The application then remains translucent after no longer being dragged and stays on top of any other applications. To return the window to normal it must be dragged around again.

Note: This problem is not affected by changing the "Transparency effects" settings in the Colors setting area to off or on. It's also not affected by changing the Control Panel settings for making windows transparent during dragging.

This issue appears to be similar to the functionality of the windows store application [WindowTop](https://github.com/BiGilSoft/WindowTop/releases), which makes can make windows translucent and allow them to be pinned over other windows (even has a very similar pin icon graphic). However, I have never manually installed this application from the windows store or github and it is not present in Apps & Features. Unsure if it is somehow silently installed by another application or Windows Update.

I did have a similar application installed called [Deskpins](https://deskpins.en.uptodown.com/windows#:%7E:text=Deskpins%20is%20a%20free%20tool,putting%20tabs%20on%20a%20page.) which I uninstalled to see if that fixed this issue and it did not. I also have [Microsoft PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) installed which also has an always-on-top feature but uninstalling PowerToys did not fix the issue either.

Any help or troubleshooting steps recommended are appreciated.

An example of what this issue looks like is shown below:

[image]

Comment: That "shaking" action is supposed to minimise (and then maximise on a second shake) all other windows, I don't know why it would make one transparent... I think you've got something seriously broken.

Comment: @Mokubai I think I vaguely remember that it used to be that way. I just checked and that feature is called Aero Shake and I checked common reasons why it might not be working (mainly Snap Windows being turned off in Multitasking Settings) but that didn't apply to me. I think if there's any way to manually re-enable Aero Shake it might fix this issue. I tried a registry tweak to enable it but that didn't work: https://winaero.com/how-to-re-enable-aero-shake-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the exact same issue. My user installed a 3-rd party software that was causing this. AquaSnap was the issue. Uninstalled and issue went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).